# Bash function to open a file in localhost

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I use Apache2 under Ubuntu 11.10, where my www folder is located under `/var/www/`, so I wrote a Bash function to open any given file under `/var/www/` in `http://localhost/`, so basically I replaced `/var/www/` with `localhost` and start Firefox from bash with the given filepath:

```
function lh {
    wd=$(pwd)
    file_path="localhost${wd:8}/$1"
    firefox $(echo "$file_path") &
}
```

The problem with that, it doesn't send the process to the background, and it outputs every action from Firefox to bash!  Can anyone help me with that?  I'm new to bash BTW.

Answer (score 3):

From a bash point of view (i.e. ignoring @dtmilano's answer which may well be 100% correct)

You don't need to do

```
firefox $(echo "$file_path") &
```

Just

```
firefox "$file_path" &
```

When I tried this in a simple script, it didn't like the 2nd invokation of firfox being too close to the first - it needed a few seconds between them so the 2nd file didn't get an error.

If you don't need the firefox output, you could direct it to /dev/null

```
firefox "$file_path" > /dev/null &
```

Comment: That is odd - certainly puts it in the bg for me.

Comment: Thanks John, I appreciated your help, the problem happend because I was logged as super user using su, you can try that yourself

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use

```
firefox file:///$PWD/$1
```

Comment: it's a php file, when I run it like that the php engine will not process that, instead it prompt download file